# Modal BootStrap can not get variable asp from codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

In MinhasVendas2.aspx :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- dialog body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        Forma de Pagamento

        <%--  <%# Eval("desc_tp_pagamento") %>
          teste--%>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">    
         Dados Pagto: <%=id_imobiliaria_pagamento%>
            <label id="lblteste"></label>    
      </div>
      <!-- dialog buttons -->
      <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" id="a.btn" class="btn btn-primary"data-dismiss="modal">OK</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            <%--#modalformapagto fim--%>
```

codebehind:

```
public void gdvPagamentos_SelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            List<pagamento> pagto = new List<pagamento>();
            var id_imobiliaria_pagamento = gdvPagamentos.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
            //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "", "myModal();", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
                 (Page,
                  this.GetType(),
                  "script",
                  "myModal();",
                  true);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){ }
    }
```

Here is the script being triggered via codebehind:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function myModal() {    
                    $("#myModal").modal();    
                    $("#myModal").on("show", function () {    // wire up the OK button to dismiss the modal when shown
                        $("#myModal a.btn").on("click", function (e) {
                            console.log("button pressed");   // just as an example...
                            $("#myModal").modal('hide');     // dismiss the dialog
                        });
                    })
                };
                    function myModalHide() {
                        $("#myModal").on("hide", function () {    // remove the event listeners when the dialog is dismissed
                            $("#myModal a.btn").off("click");
                        })
                    };

                    function myModalHidden() {
                        $("#myModal").on("hidden", function () {  // remove the actual elements from the DOM when fully hidden
                            $("#myModal").remove();
                        });

                        $("#myModal").modal({                    // wire up the actual modal functionality and show the dialog
                            "backdrop": "static",
                            "keyboard": true,
                            "show": true                     // ensure the modal is shown immediately
                        })
                    }
                ;
</script>
```

I declare the variable `id_imobiliaria_pagamento` also outside the method and the data is recovered normal in codebehind.

But this same variable, with the modal open, and called in the html code inside the modal, shows nothing. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the codebehind, inside the method I had declared the variable in a form (example var xxxxx) and out of the method I had defined as string ... with this was occurring the problem of not displaying it ... Strange that did not accuse error . I corrected for tb string inside the method and the contents of the variables came to be displayed.